# is it possible to draw on road based on a location near it

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am currently developing an application that tracks your path, so it always draws on the map. I want to know if it is possible to draw on the road, since my application gets my location and its not precise, its always near(about 30 m radius) me. I want it not to add it where it is, but on the nearest road

Comment: which api are you using Google Map api v1 or v2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the path on the map using the `Ployline` class of Google Map as below:

> ```
>   Polyline line=myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())).color(Color.RED));
> ```

For more details about it please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines)

Comment: I'm sorry if i wasn't clear. My application draws on the map! I want it to draw on the roads of that map